# Show speed in Finder Copy progress window

Tags: finder, macos

Is there a way to show more details in the Finder copy window? I'm mainly interested in the speed.

Comment: great question . i have been trying to find this for a while. I think google should point us to some app

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK here isn't any "builtin/hidden solution".

You can get (probably rough) numbers:

- open Applications -> Utilities -> Monitor Activity
- Select Disk Activity and you get actual IO/Data speed.